# How can I improve this table (using tabularx)?

Tags: tabularx

I'm trying to make a table look pretty; more specifically, I want the 1st and 3rd columns to be 6-6.5 cm wide, and I want the second column to be only 1-1.5 cm wide. I also want minimal white space in the top and bottom cells.

Could you help me? What's the easiest way to do that? I'm a total `tabularx` newbie...

[image]

Here is what I put together with `tabular`... (less complicated tham with `tabularx`)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\begin{document}

\resizebox{14cm}{!}{  
\setstretch{1}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{|p{6cm}|p{3cm}|p{7cm}|}\hline
      % after \\: \hline or \cline{col1-col2} \cline{col3-col4} ...
      Vecindario & Evaluaciones de $f$ & Perspectiva General \\
      \hline
      Añadiendo al anterior, el intercambio de tareas de la primera y última posición (6 vecinos)& 6 & \includegraphics[width=70mm]{opvec2.eps} \\
      \hline
      Generando una permutación aleatoria en cada iteración e intercambiando las tareas en las posiciones que ocupan 1-2,3-4,5-6 (3 vecinos)  & 3 & \includegraphics[width=70mm]{opvec2.eps} \\
      \hline
      Generando una permutación aleatoria en cada iteración e intercambiando las tareas en las posiciones que ocupan 1-2,2-3,3-4,4-5,5-6,6-1 (6 vecinos)& 6 & \includegraphics[width=70mm]{opvec2.eps} \\
      \hline
      Intercambiando la tarea de la 1ª posición con todas las demás; la de la 2ª con todas las siguientes; la de la 3ª con todas las siguientes posiciones;....;y la de la penúltima posición con la tarea de la última posición& 15 & \includegraphics[width=70mm]{opvec2.eps} \\
      \hline
\end{tabular}\\
}
\setstretch{1.5}

{\small ''Iteraciones máximas''=20}
\end{document}
```

And this is what I did using `tabularx`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\begin{document}

\setstretch{1}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\hsize=\hsize}X>{\hsize=0.25\hsize}X>{\hsize=\hsize}X}
      \hline
      % after \\: \hline or \cline{col1-col2} \cline{col3-col4} ...
      Vecindario & Evaluaciones de $f$ & Perspectiva General \\
      \hline
      Añadiendo al anterior, el intercambio de tareas de la primera y última posición (6 vecinos)& 6 & \includegraphics[width=70mm]{opvec2.eps} \\
      \hline
      Generando una permutación aleatoria en cada iteración e intercambiando las tareas en las posiciones que ocupan 1-2,3-4,5-6 (3 vecinos)  & 3 & \includegraphics[width=70mm]{opvec2.eps} \\
      \hline
      Generando una permutación aleatoria en cada iteración e intercambiando las tareas en las posiciones que ocupan 1-2,2-3,3-4,4-5,5-6,6-1 (6 vecinos)& 6 & \includegraphics[width=70mm]{opvec2.eps} \\
      \hline
      Intercambiando la tarea de la 1ª posición con todas las demás; la de la 2ª con todas las siguientes; la de la 3ª con todas las siguientes posiciones;....;y la de la penúltima posición con la tarea de la última posición& 15 & \includegraphics[width=70mm]{opvec2.eps} \\
      \hline

\end{tabularx}\\
\setstretch{1.5}

{\small ''Iteraciones máximas''=20}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the possibility of a pagebreak inside the tabular use package `ltablex` instead of `tabularx`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{mwe}%% Only for demo needed

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} >{\vspace{0pt}}X >{\vspace{0pt}}p{1cm} >{\vspace{0pt}}X @{}}\toprule
\emph{Vecindario} & \hspace{0pt}\emph{Evaluciones de $f$} & \emph{Perspectiva General}\\\midrule 
The mwe package has due to its nature a little uncommon installation requirements.
While the normal package files are installed as normal, a variety of image files
are installed in the tex/latex/mwe/ folder, so that they can be accessed from
every (MWE) document. & 6 & 
   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}\\\midrule
The mwe package has due to its nature a little uncommon installation requirements.
While the normal package files are installed as normal, a variety of image files
are installed in the tex/latex/mwe/ folder, so that they can be accessed from
every (MWE) document. & 3 & 
   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}\\\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

and the adopted example for two columns. Important is that you use `\newline` in the first column, otherwise you'll get a new tabular line and the image starts with the last line (I run it with `pdflatex`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs,setspace}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\begin{document}
Hola\\
tronquito
\setstretch{1}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} >{\vspace{0pt}}X >{\vspace{0pt}}X @{}}\toprule
\emph{Vecindario}  & \emph{Perspectiva General}\\\midrule
Añadiendo al anterior vecindario, el intercambio de tareas de la primera y última posición.\newline
\textbf{Nº de vecinos: 6.}\newline
\textbf{Nº de evaluaciones/iteración: 6} & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{opvec2.eps}\\ \midrule
Generando una permutación aleatoria en cada iteración e intercambiando las tareas en las posiciones que ocupan 1-2,3-4,5-6.\newline
\textbf{Nº de vecinos: 3.}\newline
Nº de evaluaciones/iteración: 3   &
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{opvec2.eps} \\ \midrule
Generando una permutación aleatoria en cada iteración e intercambiando las tareas en las posiciones que ocupan 1-2,2-3,3-4,4-5,5-6,6-1.\newline
\textbf{Nº de vecinos: 6.}\newline
Nº de evaluaciones/iteración: 6 &
   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{opvec2.eps}\\ \midrule
Intercambiando la tarea de la 1ª posición con todas las demás; la de la 2ª con todas las siguientes; la de la 3ª con todas las siguientes posiciones;....;y la de la penúltima posición con la tarea de la última posición.\newline
\textbf{Nº de vecinos: 15.}\newline
Nº de evaluaciones/iteración: 15   &
   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{opvec2.eps}\\ \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\setstretch{1.5}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I adapted your example to 2 cols but... What am I doing bad to obatin this http://sensa.square7.ch/gfdgfd6.jpg ?  TEX-file -> https://www.dropbox.com/s/p7u3lbjle4pz9p6/proba42.tex

Comment: you cannot have a linebreak inside of `\textbf{ ...\\ ...}`. Use the macro two times: `\textbf{ ...}\\ \textbf{ ...}`

Comment: \herbert Thank you very much, but still haveing problems with the adaptation https://www.dropbox.com/s/4qe72h4qyqyp8io/proba42-soo.tex

Comment: see my edited answer.

Comment: ok Thank you. but It have again white big white spaces like my initial post http://sensa.square7.ch/gjnghg7.jpg . You´re so good but It´s so frustating annoying you with this kind of questions!! I like the result of LATEX but.. . It´s so complicated!!!  Sometimes.... I would like LATEX would be as easy as Word!! :-)

Comment: post your code ...

Comment: ok. It´s exactly the second of your post. COPY & PASTE 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/fdhfrdu82eppdwc/proba45.tex

Comment: provide also the image

Comment: Occurs the same if you put example-image-a instead opvec2.eps --     The iamges are equal to this https://www.dropbox.com/s/ehmialhq14s43fd/opvec2.eps

Comment: see edit. Use `\newline` if you want only a new line in the tabular cell but not a new tabular line.

Answer (score 2):

> `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\hsize=\hsize}X>{\hsize=0.25\hsize}X>{\hsize=\hsize}X}`

`\hsize=\hsize` does nothing so that is

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X  >{\hsize=0.25\hsize}X X}
```

If you alter the size you need to make sure that the total width is unchanged so you would need to change the widths of the other two.  However there is no point in making the second two columns X as they are fixed width (of the digits or the specified image width of 70mm)

so you should use

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Xcc}
```

Then to make the image look better you need to make its baseline go through its center by

```
 \raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics.....}
```

Or you can use the `adjustbox` package which avoids the need to use `\raisebox` by giving `\includegraphics` options to control the vertical alignment.

Answer (score 2):

With `\raisebox` the reference point of the graphics can be changed. The following example defines macro `\tabgraphics` as shorthand for `\includegraphics`, whose reference point is moved below the top by the amount of the height of an uppercase letter. Also inside an `X` cell the maximum width is `\hsize`. Also the sum of `\hsize` in the `tabularx` columns specification should sum up to the number of `X` columns.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\newcommand*{\tabgraphics}[2][]{%
  \begingroup
    \settoheight{\dimen0}{H}%
    \raisebox{\dimexpr\dimen0-\height}{%
      \includegraphics[width=\hsize,{#1}]{#2}%
    }%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\setstretch{1}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\hsize=1.3\hsize}X>{\hsize=0.3\hsize}X>{\hsize=1.4\hsize}X}
  \hline
  % after \\: \hline or \cline{col1-col2} \cline{col3-col4} ...
  Vecindario & \hspace{0pt}Evaluaciones de~$f$ & Perspectiva General \\
  \hline
  Añadiendo al anterior, el intercambio de tareas de la primera y última posición (6 vecinos)& 6 &
  \tabgraphics{opvec2} \\
  \hline
  Generando una permutación aleatoria en cada iteración e intercambiando las tareas en las posiciones que ocupan 1-2,3-4,5-6 (3 vecinos)  & 3 &
  \tabgraphics{opvec2} \\
  \hline
  Generando una permutación aleatoria en cada iteración e intercambiando las tareas en las posiciones que ocupan 1-2,2-3,3-4,4-5,5-6,6-1 (6 vecinos)& 6 &
  \tabgraphics{opvec2} \\
  \hline
  Intercambiando la tarea de la 1ª posición con todas las demás; la de la 2ª con todas las siguientes; la de la 3ª con todas las siguientes posiciones;....;y la de la penúltima posición con la tarea de la última posición& 15 &
  \tabgraphics{opvec2} \\
  \hline

\end{tabularx}\\
\setstretch{1.5}

{\small ``Iteraciones máximas''=20}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]